# Можно ли было использовать местоимение "мы" в косвенной речи, заключенной в кавычки?

Tags: цитирование

Летом он собирается заняться здоровьем, «обдумать положение, в котором мы все находимся».

Можно ли было использовать местоимение "мы" в косвенной речи, заключенной в кавычки?

Хотя это, конечно, не косвенная речь, а цитирование.

Но бывают случаи, когда часть цитаты вводится в виде прямой речи. Например,

N говорил (писал, считал, полагал), что «цитата».

Суть моего вопроса была в том, что можно ли было использовать личное местоимение первого лица в цитате в виде косвенной речи.

Мать сказала: «Мы успеем вернуться к понедельнику».

Можно ли так переписать цитату в виде косвенной речи в кавычках:

Мать сказала, что «мы успеем вернуться к понедельнику».

Если нужно сохранить дословность, но не использовать двоеточие.

Comment: *что «мы успеем вернуться к понедельнику»* — об этом уже был вопрос, но ваш первый пример сложнее, там смесь и "мы" может относиться и к читающему.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не косвенная речь, а цитата. Косвенная речь не пишется в кавычках.